# Unit Testing Public Signed .NET Core/Framework Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit, strongname

I have a NuGet package library project that is compiling for .NET Core and .NET Framework. It is also using the new [public signing](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/public-signing.md).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Build">
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Label="Signing">
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>../../Key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <PublicSign>true</PublicSign>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I have an xUnit test project using which is also cross compiling to .NET Core and .NET Framework.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Build">
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Label="Package References">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Label="Project References">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Source\Foo\Foo.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run the tests in this project, the .NET Core test run succeeds but the .NET Framework test run fails with:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Foo, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fc5550082a9c642c' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

How can I get them both to work?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [Support multiple .NET versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks).

Comment: Most likely one of your libraries has a higher version

Comment: How about to properly sign the assemblies? At least for the .NET Framework you can ifdef in the msbuild project to fully sign your assemblies. As the documentation states "You will not be able to load the assembly in an AppDomain where shadow copying is turned on." which is used by xunit (see denied PR https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/pull/9).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<PublicSign Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">True</PublicSign>
```

Reference

[#SNMP Library](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/11.3.0/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj#L26)

Comment: Looks like I can remove `<PublicSign>` since proper signing is now implemented cross platform https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8210.